# Is recycling the App Pool necessary after changing website physical paths

Tags: iis, web-deployment, octopus-deploy

My deployment process for an MVC5 website looks a little bit like this:

- Get nuget package from TeamCity build and extract that to a new directory e.g. `C:/website/r1.0.1`
- Update IIS Website and Virtual app physical paths to point to this new directory
- Delete old directory

I found yesterday when I deployed a new version of the site that the virtual app was still referencing the old directory (which broke as it had been deleted), even though the physical path in IIS was pointing to the new directory. I fixed this by recycling the App pool for the virtual app.

I was wondering how this might have happened. Does IIS do some sort of caching that may have caused this? Should I simply make recycling the App Pools after setting the physical paths part of the deployment process?

Comment: Kind of bizarre way to deploy. Why do you want to do it this way? Usually you have folder, say C:/website, then you clean up the old website, deploy it there, not touching the physical paths at all. Either way, recycling app pool after changing physical path seems reasonable to me.

Comment: The idea was to have less downtime

Comment: If you load balance things you don't need to worry about that. That said, if recycling stuff has any bad sides for you, you can write a script which checks if the physical path change has kicked in(with powershell, through REST call to version.txt or whatever), and if it hasn't, restart the app pool cycle.

Comment: We don't have the sort of resources that would justify load balancing. We now recycle the app pool every time we deploy, I was just wondering the reasons why this is necessary and what IIS might is doing behind the scenes.